# Blue arrows on folders within additional mailbox

Tags: outlook

I have a user who we added an additional mailbox.  They are keeping all emails coming into this, which in turn is increasing the size of the mailbox.  So I created a PST file to store all the emails in.  This user checks the mailbox's inbox and then moves them to the appropriate folder within the pst file.  Well at least that is my theory.

However all the current folders in that additional mailbox have double end straight blue arrows.  When we try to move the folder to the pst file we get the following error.

"Cannot move the items.  Cannot copy this folder because it may contain private items"

I am certain it has to do with the blue arrows, so I am trying to determine what they are there for and how to remove.  I have read comments on offline files, but offline files is disabled on this system.  And I have also read comments on synchronization, but no luck.

Anybody else seen this before or come across this before?

Oh and by the way, this is office 2007 she is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you move the bottom-most folder in a subtree over? i.e., maybe you can't move Inbox, but you can move Inbox/stuff?

Also if you log in as the second mailbox and go to Tools, Options, Delegates, is the "Delegate can see my private items" box unchecked? If so, check it.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue, although in my case I could move single folders out of the shared mailbox into the .pst file but folders that contained subfolders refused to move or even copy, claiming they contained private items.

Moving each folder one by one was impractical, but I discovered a workaround.  Create a new Outlook profile where the shared mailbox is your primary (and only) mailbox.  Then load this profile and there are no problems moving folders with all subfolders in one go.  Then when you're done, close Outlook and go back to the original profile.